# What should I set my managed stripping level to?

Tags: unity

I know the higher the Managed Stripping Level the smaller binary size but I also know the higher the level more issues you can run into so I have some questions about all this.

1. If I set my managed stripping level to high will I see the effect of that and be able to properly test it when running my game in the editor or would I have to compile to make sure everything runs alright?
2. Can issues with a high managed stripping level be platform specific (Meaning a high level is good on one platform but causes issues on another)?
3. Does managed stripping level only effect binary size or can it also effect performance? If it can effect performance would a binary with a high managed stripping level run faster than a binary with a low managed stripping level or would it be the other way around?

Comment: You should always test your compiled game on each of your target platforms regularly, no matter what you've set the managed stripping level to. Internet hearsay is never a reason to test less.

Comment: @DMGregory I never said it was, I'm just asking these questions so I can get a good idea on how the stripping level will effect the games I develop in the future and knowing if potential problems are platform specific would be a super helpful thing to know.